# Is it possible to copy remote origin url to clipboard using Bash on Mac (Darwin 17)?

Tags: git, bash, macos, clipboard, pbcopy

I've tried one command line:
`pbcopy < git remote get-url origin`

And other way:
`output.txt < git remote get-url origin`

But I get next message:

> -bash: git: No such file or directory

Any ways?

**P.S.** Git version: 2.13.3, OS Version: macOS High Sierra (Darwin 17).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to redirect output to file `output.txt` it would be:
`git remote get-url origin > output.txt`

For clipboard do:
`git remote get-url origin | pbcopy`

Comment: Nice, it works! What's about the transfer of the git output to clipboard without saving in any files? Whether you know or don't?

Comment: Huh! It's more simpler than I thought.. Appreciate it!

Comment: Yeah, I do recommend you reading a bit about redirecting output of commands in your terminal with `|`, `>` and `>>`